# Minimal size of the maximal biclique

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

We examine a [bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph) graph with two sides $R$ and $L$, and denote by $|L|$ and $|R|$ the number of nodes in each side. We know only that each node on side $R$ is connected to $k$ nodes on side $L$, that $|R| < k< |L|$, and that $k$ is much larger than $|R|$.

What is the minimal size (*i.e.*, number of edges) of the maximal biclique<sup>1</sup>?

<sup>1</sup>maximal biclique: A complete bipartite subgraph, that isn't a subgraph of another complete bipartite subgraph.

Comment: would you please state what $\ll$ is supposed to mean here? Also: I, and I think, many others, would prefer the capital letter $K$ be replaced with $k$. (The latter is 'mere' tradition of course, i.e. to try to have notation and capitalization reflect the types of objects.) @ Daniel Soudry

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question to modify and clarify notation like you asked. in other words "$\ll$" is just an inequality in which one side is much larger than the other side.

Comment: @DanielSoudry I expect that by $|R| \ll k$ you mean that $R$ is "much *smaller* than $k$".  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, clarified (I guess I am still thinking  about inequalities in my native right-to-left language).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answer is 2.  Start with a disjoint union of stars, each with the center in $R$ and $k$ leaves in $L$.  Now pick two of those stars and identify a single leaf in each.  You get a copy of $K_{2,1}$ that is a maximal biclique.
(It is certainly not *maximum*, but that is not what was asked.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow:
1) What is $K_{2,1}$ and what did you mean by "copy"?
2) Why is this a biclique (i.e., complete biparatite subgraph)?
Thanks!

Comment: @DanielSoudry In general $K_{a,b}$ means a bipartite graph with $a$ vertices on one side, $b$ vertices on the other side, and all possible edges between the two sides.  So $K_{2,1}$ is simply a path on 3 vertices.  By "copy of $K_{2,1}$" I mean that $K_{2,1}$ appears as a subgraph.  From the definition of $K_{2,1}$ now it should be clear that this is a biclique.  It is maximal because those two centers with a common neighbor have no other common neighbors and their common neighbor has no other neighbors at all.

Comment: Oh, I see it wasn't clear to me that "identify" means that both stars have only one common leaf. I see your point now. I'll open another question on "maximum", and give you the answer... Thanks!

Comment: Wait, but this is not true if there is too much unavoidable overlap. For example, if $|R|=2, k=5, |L|=6$ then the minimal maximal bicluque has size $2×4=8$. @Dan Cranston